# Averaging a dictinary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, average

My dictionary is being read from a .CSV file into python, however i then need to average the scores in this dictionary.

```
Classopen = open("Student" + "class" + str(classes) + ".csv","rb")
Classfile = csv.reader(Classopen)
Classdict = {}

for people in Classfile:
    students = people[0]
    studentvalue = str(people[1])
    if students in Classdict:
        Classdict[students].append(people)
    else :
        Classdict[students] = [studentvalue]
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, post your code as text.

Comment: what is `people` in this code? It looks like a single row of a csv, but should that ever be appended to `Classdict[students]`? Shouldn't `Classdict[students]` just be score values? `people` should also contain their name.

Comment: If you could post a row or two of your input file, that would clear up everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calculate sum of all values for each student and divide in to count of values:

```
for student in classdict:
    sum(map(int, classdict[student])) / float(len(classdict[student]))
```

If you do `studentvalue = int(people[1])` instead of `studentvalue = str(people[1])` it would be even simple:

```
for student in classdict:
    print("{} - {}".format(student, sum(classdict[student]) / float(len(classdict[student]))))
```

Comment: This returns the students scores, how can i add there names there aswell?

Comment: Just print student - it's key, i've edited second variant to show you.

Comment: I'm not sure this does what you think it does. `Classdict[students]` seems to be a list of lists and at least one of those values might be a student name.

Comment: This doesn't work it brings the error argument must be a string or a number, not 'list

Comment: Classdict is simply where i store the information from a .CSV file